# How do I the get inner text in orchestral xml parser?

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I have a xml snippet that I want to parse with Orchestral XMLParser in Laravel.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<course code="ABC">
   <title lang="sv">Utmattning</title>
   <title lang="en">Fatigue</title>
</course>
```

The following code is used to try to parse it

```
$file = file_get_contents('file.xml');

$xml = XmlParser::extract($file);

$array = $xml->parse([
  'code' => ['uses' => '::code'],
  'title' => ['uses' => 'title[::lang>locale, value>name]'],
)];
```

This is what I get

```
[
  [code] => ABC
  [title] =>
  [
    [locale] => sv
    [name] => 
  ],
  [
    [locale] => en
    [name] => 
  ]
]
```

But I want to get

```
[
  [code] => ABC
  [title] =>
  [
    [locale] => sv
    [name] => Utmattning
  ],
  [
    [locale] => en
    [name] => Fatigure
  ]
]
```

How can I replace the "value" to fetch the inner text of the element title?

Comment: Never used it but reading https://github.com/orchestral/parser would make me inclined to try`'title::lang>locale,title>name`

Comment: Tried your proposal, but it yields the same empty result. I tried to figure out by looking at the test documents in the git: 

https://github.com/orchestral/parser/blob/master/tests/Feature/DocumentTest.php

But couldn't find anything that helped out for this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding an new operator to the structure, called "!" which fetches the inner text of the active element.

https://github.com/laravie/parser/pull/15

Maybe not the cleanest solution, but it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `title[::lang=@]`

See https://github.com/laravie/parser/blob/master/tests/Xml/DocumentTest.php#L331-L356

When you do `value>name` it expect to have `<title><value>Content</value></title>`

Comment: Is there somewhere a documentation of the combination of :: > = () @ ? When I tried title[::lang=@] it still doesn't get the content of the element. I guess that title[::lang=@] should result in title => ['sv'=>'Utmatting', 'en' => 'Fatigue'] ?

Comment: If I alter the xml file and add a tag around the title elements called <titles>. Thereafter change the query to titles[title(::lang=@)] it works.